# Bootstrap and grocery_CRUD css priority

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I'm on a web project using bootstrap style, then I incorpored the grocery_CRUD framework and I started having problems with the css.
It seems the grocery_CRUD has priority on the css files, when it renders a table, all style changes.

I want all web site has the bootstrap css and only the tables rendered with grocery_CRUD has its style.

Any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer my question:
It's all about order of loading CSS... just didn't think about it, need to load first grocery_crud theme and then my css file. I had backwards overwriting my style

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the "bootstrap" theme at grocery CRUD. Just be aware that it is still in BETA phase. You can simply have a bootstrap theme like this:

```
$crud->set_theme('twitter-bootstrap');
```

Comment: uhm, I don't want that. I just want to keep the bootstrap style on my header, I styled using bootstrap classes, but when in the page renders a groceryCrud table ALL the website changes the style. I want to keep my header style always like this: [header](https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/624x187q90/674/61XZ3q.jpg)

sorry if I didnt explain well